# How to display the values in a multi-dimensional array row-wise?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a multi-dimensional array:

```
string[,] array_questions = new string[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];

for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        array_questions[i, j] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
}

foreach (string number in array_questions)
{
    Response.Write(number + "\n");
}
```

But it displays the entire array in one single lengthy row. How can I display it row-wise in the aspx page?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `foreach` loop for rectangle two dimensional array will return **all** elements from that array one at a time. You need to use indexes to access rows and columns of a two-dimensional array.

Go through each row and display each element. Then add paragraph (new line) after each row.

Example is given below:

```
for (int row = 0; row < array_questions.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < array_questions.GetLength(1); column++)
    {
        //writing data, you probably want to add comma after it
        Response.Write(array_questions[row,column]); 
    }

    //adding new line, so that next loop will start from new line
    Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

for array of 5 rows and 10 columns of default `int` values, I've received next table

```
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

If you had correctly populated `array_questions` before, you should receive table-view data on page, resulted in `Response.Write` calls.

---

A much cleaner solution would be to reuse `dt` (I assume it's a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx)) `Rows` property, which is `IEnumerable<DataRowCollection>`. Next code achieves similar behavior, but in much cleaner fashion, and you don't need another array.

```
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
{
    Response.Write(string.Join(", ", row) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

will print data in next table-like fashion:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Alternatively you could string.Join somehow. I'm not sure exactly what you would give it as the array-parameter though. Maybe an ArraySegment could work?

Comment: @Alxandr yes, `string.Join` would work perfectly on a jagged array, but in case of rectangle array, there is no build-in mechanism to retrieve separate rows and lines. [ArraySergment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) works on  one-dimensional array (or jagged arrays, which is basically a one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays).

Comment: @IlyaIvanov you are right. I looked it up. Though I must say there should be a structure for this (like ArraySegment, but maybe something like ArrayDimention or whatever). And string.Join takes an enumerable (though it's probably not as efficient as giving it an array). Your double loop is probably the best solution still though.

Comment: @ Ilya Ivanov  
but it shows an Error :The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments ..please help

Comment: @user2431727 Then use the first options.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
        Response.Write(String.Join(", ", dt.Rows[r][c].ToString())); 
    }
    Response.Write("<br />");
}
```

Comment: as far as I understood, OP want's actual values of `array_questions` formatted in table, not the count of each dimension.

Comment: it show  Error : The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

what You think about this way?

```
   for (int r = 0; r < table.GetLength(0); r++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < table.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            Console.Write((table[r, k] + " " ));
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```